# .htaccess redirect https://www to https://non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have a 301 redirect from all domains to https://example.de.
The redirect works with http://www.example, www.example with all tld (.com,.eu.net).
But with https://www.example it doesnt redirect to https without the www.
Here is the Mod rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.at$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.at$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.eu$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Edit:
The following works so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: down vote and no answer, i love this community....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule doesn't redirect `https` urls because you are not using correct Rewrite Conditions. Also you dont need to write multiple conditions to test a domain name. Instead of using two `RewriteCond` lines to test `www.example.com` and `example.com` you  can do  it in a single condition something like. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$` .

The following is the shorter version of your rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.at$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [OR]
 # the main domain. redirect www.example.de to example.de
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.at$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: thanks you, i tried it and got error 500 (script failure)

Comment: @Tobiass There was a typo and I have fixed it. Check the updated version.

Comment: thanks i will test it in a few minutes, why is the domain example.at instead of example.de in the last RewriteCond?

Comment: perfect i think it works, i will test it with all domains. Your code is faster right?